QGIS- Do Triggers Bypass Default Values in SpatiaLite?
I'm working with SpatiaLite and using triggers to update or insert data into other tables.
Is it expected behavior, or could it be a bug, that when I insert a new feature using a trigger, such as:
INSERT INTO mytable(field1)
values('Mystring')

If the table has default values (e.g., automatic surface calculations, update dates, etc.), these defaults values are not applied. Instead, they need to be set directly within the trigger.
Is this the intended functionality?
